# Best way to simultaneously control two servos positioned horizontally and vertically?

Tags: c, servo

I'm trying to set up a C program where a servo (servo1) sweeps to a position, waits a few seconds, moves to another position and repeats 4 more times. Another servo, positioned vertically, (servo2) is supposed to move up and hold its position, especially during the period where servo1 is waiting. I have servo2 running in an infinite loop as a separate thread, but I am unsure if if this is the best course of action.

The problem is that servo2 either falls and loses its position if it is not consistently receiving a signal,
or if it keeps getting a signal, it constantly hums and sometimes jumps around. I'm not sure if it jumps because if there are interrupts in the background (I'm using a cubieboard running linux).

I'd like servo 2 to not jerk around at all. Any help or suggestions on implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided more information on what you are trying to achieve. If you need to hold a static load, a stepper motor would be a better solution. I had this issue when I used servos for a project. Switching to stepper motors resulted in much smoother control with no jitter. http://www.amci.com/tutorials/tutorials-stepper-vs-servo.asp

Answer (score 1):

What kind of servos do you have?

As far as i know there ar analog servos which you can drive with a pwm. Every microcontroller i have seen has some pwm outputs. With them you can generate the signal and it runs in the background without any processor resources needed.

When you then stepwise change the ontime period of one pwm the other one should rest as it was. So no multi threading is needed in this case and solving your problem is really easy and straighforward.

Comment: The servos are Hitec HS-645MG which are digital. For some reason the board has only two pwm outputs and they are being used for something else that I can't change.
Also after servo1 sweeps completely, servo2 moves up even further for servo1 to sweep again and repeats a third time

Comment: Do you have some timers left? You can create an interrupt with these and then toggle the signals in the interrupt. Or other possible solution which isn't this nice are timing events counted with a loopdelay in the main. Do you know how i mean?

Comment: I don't think any timers are used. I forgot that I attempted to mess with them but my knowledge is limited in using them. Is there a good guide or pseudocode for using them? Most I see are for avr which is hard for me to generalize how to set flags for any microcontroller

Comment: Which uC do you have? Pic?

Comment: I'm using a cubieboard3/cubietruck  which is similar to a raspberry pi and uses an Allwinner A20 processor. I've looked through the data sheet of the processor but my trouble is equating flags of those timers with those in avr or other tutorials I see. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://lib.chipdip.ru/974/DOC000974439.pdf&ved=0CDEQFjAFahUKEwjdsbPY3o3HAhVFHT4KHeobChc&usg=AFQjCNG-Zflcr5pxk3Z3u25x0ioEvXUZ4w&sig2=Efl7yPdyJ7FCdSL90o1KCg

Comment: In General every timer has a clock source, here you have the input frequency. Some timers have then a fixed or various prescaler (sometimes also both). This is then the counting frequency. There are timers with a comparison register. There you can set a comparing number, at which number an interrupt should ne generated. The other kind doesn't have such a compare register and they generate an interrupt when the overflow (@8bit this would be after TMRX=255). To make this a little more complicated some timers also have a postscaler if you want to route them out directly.

Comment: A timer normaly starts at 0 but can also have a reload value (you can set this also manually if you need to). So you have many parameters to scale the clock appropriate to your application. There are the interrupts then or the output after an additional postscaler which you can use. E.g. as the needed interrupt or sometimes also as a source for a different component. The timers all have some different possibilities and different uses. On page 108 you get an idea which one may is free and you could use. Afterwards read carefully through the registerfunctions. Hope this helps